# losing css styles in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I  generate this scaffold
rails generate scaffold Caa::Documents name1: ......
wich has created this scss file
app/assets/stylesheets/caa/documents.css.scss

I have local clone (git clone) of production app (rails 3.2.21  ,ruby 1.9.3. p0)  where this scss file works perfectly.

but when I have pushed (git) back to production server (rails 4.1.0 , ruby 1.9.3.p0)
corresponding views lost scss s from that file. when I press F12 in browser  this file is missing from css list.

Im adding this component at already existing big project  thats why Im lost .
(all new files are from scaffold generate)

I understand that exact answer is hard to find without having access to code
but you can give me an advice  from where I should start research and what could be a reason ?

thanks

Comment: Did you do `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: thanks for answer . I think you are right.
I have checked and "assets:precompile" is commented in our custom update script. 
I will read more about assets:precompile to find reason why previous dev commented it and to  ensure not to break something :).